# How to read BigDecimal format in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bigdecimal

After running my RSpec tests I frequently get output like this:

```
expected: 50
     got: #<BigDecimal:7fbdcd1b5408,'0.22E3',9(36)>
```

How can I find out what number RSpec actually got?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It says 0.22E3, which I think means 0.22 x10^3 = 220.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @jcm commented, It's `220`. (= 0.22 * 10<sup>3</sup>)

```
require 'bigdecimal'
BigDecimal.new(220) # => #<BigDecimal:3037368,'0.22E3',9(36)>
BigDecimal.new(220) == 220 # => true
```

Comment: OK, thanks. It would be nice if it could be calculated vice versa somehow.

Comment: @Tintin81, Try `0.22E3` in IRB.

Comment: ok this was very weird for me... but I did that once, it worked, but forgot to commit. Next time I ran the spec WITHOUT the bigdecimal.new and it STILL worked???